# Differing sizes of String representation in Java

Tags: java

I'm comparing the various ways of storing a `String` in java by breaking a `String` down into its constituent parts.  I have this code snippet:

```
final String message = "ABCDEFGHIJ";
System.out.println("As String " + RamUsageEstimator.humanSizeOf(message));
System.out.println("As byte[] " + RamUsageEstimator.humanSizeOf(message.getBytes()));
System.out.println("As char[] " + RamUsageEstimator.humanSizeOf(message.toCharArray()));
```

This is using [sizeof](https://github.com/dweiss/java-sizeof) to measure the size of the objects.  The results of the above show:

```
As String 64 bytes
As byte[] 32 bytes
As char[] 40 bytes
```

Given that a `byte` is 8 bits and a `char` is 16 bits why are the results not 10 bytes and 20 bytes respectively?

Also what is the overhead for the `String` object that causes it to be twice the size of the underlying `byte[]`?

This is using

```
java version "1.8.0_60"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_60-b27)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.60-b23, mixed mode)
```

On OSX

Comment: To get a good answer, you need to specify the exact JVM you're using.

Comment: A String also contains: int offset, int hashcode, int length in oracle java, those make 12 bytes, leaving 2 bytes for the pointer to the array, I assume..

Comment: @Ferrybig The three `int` fields only add up to 12 bytes, but there is an object header as well. The size of the array reference depends on the VM (32/64 bit) and its settings (whether it uses compressed pointers or not). Then there's the question of alignment and of course it would be nice to know how  `RamUsageEstimator` actually works. (And Java 8 did away with the `offset` and `length` fields.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The data below is for Hotspot / Java 8 - numbers will vary for other JVMs/Java versions (for example, in Java 7, `String` has two additional `int` fields).

A `new Object()` takes 12 bytes of memory (due to internal things such as the object header).

A String has (number of bytes in brackets):

- an object header (12),
- a reference to a `char[]` (4 - assuming compressed OOP in 64 bit JVM),
- an `int hash` (4).

That's 20 bytes but objects get padded to multiples of 8 bytes => 24. So that's already 24 bytes on top of the actual content of the array.

The `char[]` has a header (12), a length (4) and each char (10 x 2 = 20) padded to the next multiple of 8 - or 40 in total.

The `byte[]` has a header (12), a length (4) and each byte (10 x 1 = 10) = 26, padded to the next multiple of 8 = 32.

So we get to your numbers.

Also note that the number of bytes depends on the encoding you use - if you retry with `message.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_16)` for example, you will see that the byte array uses 40 bytes instead of 32.

---

You can use [jol](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jol/) to visualise the memory usage and confirm the calculation above. The output for the `char[]` is:

```
 OFFSET  SIZE  TYPE DESCRIPTION                    VALUE
      0     4       (object header)                01 00 00 00 (00000001 00000000 00000000 00000000) (1)
      4     4       (object header)                00 00 00 00 (00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000) (0)
      8     4       (object header)                41 00 00 f8 (01000001 00000000 00000000 11111000) (-134217663)
     12     4       (object header)                0a 00 00 00 (00001010 00000000 00000000 00000000) (10)
     16    20  char [C.<elements>                  N/A
     36     4       (loss due to the next object alignment)
Instance size: 40 bytes (reported by Instrumentation API)
```

So you can see the header of 12 (first 3 lines), the length (line 4), the chars (line 5) and the padding (line 6).

Similarly for the String (note that this excludes the size of the array itself):

```
 OFFSET  SIZE   TYPE DESCRIPTION                    VALUE
      0     4        (object header)                01 00 00 00 (00000001 00000000 00000000 00000000) (1)
      4     4        (object header)                00 00 00 00 (00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000) (0)
      8     4        (object header)                da 02 00 f8 (11011010 00000010 00000000 11111000) (-134216998)
     12     4 char[] String.value                   [A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J]
     16     4    int String.hash                    0
     20     4        (loss due to the next object alignment)
Instance size: 24 bytes (reported by Instrumentation API)
```

Answer (score 1):

Each of your test, estimates the size of an `Object`. In the first case a `String` object, in the second a `byte` array object, and finally a `char` array object. Every object, as instance of a class, may contains some private attributes and other things like that; so you cannot expect something better than: a `String` of 10 chars, contains at least the 10 chars, each of 2 bytes long, then the whole size should be ≥20 bytes, which is coherent with your results.

For the byte/char comparison you are wrong, because the byte array from a string will give you all the bytes for a given encoding. It may happens that your current encoding uses more than one byte for a char.

You may have a look at Java source code for `Object`, `String` class and array support in JVM to understand what happens exactly.

Comment: Where can the source code be found of the `array` class  you mention? Never known this class existed in java

Comment: @Ferrybig There is no source code. All array classes are synthesised by the JVM as required.

Comment: This is a built-in type, with special support.